# Find IP of raspberry pi by scanning IPs with Python

Tags: python, networking, raspberry-pi

I use a Raspberry Pi which gets its IP address from a DHCP host in our company network. I'd like to find out its IP address without having a display connected.

It's quite obvious how to scan through a range of possible IPs using Python for instance, but how do I check if there is a Raspberry Pi on the other end of the line?

Here is what I've tried so far (there should be an open ssh port on the device), but I haven't found the Raspberry Pi yet. Now I am not sure whether my Raspi isn't properly connected or my method is not working at all:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

for i in range(1,256):
    ip = '192.168.132.{}'.format(i)
    try:
        s.connect((ip, 22))
        print('Raspi is probably on {}'.format(ip))
    except socket.error as e:
        print('Nothing on {}.'.format(ip))
    s.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is looking for any device with the ssh port 22 open.  So you could get false positives.  Also, if the Pi does not open port 22 by default, then you will not get a match.

You could use a (non-Python) utility like nmap (nmap.org) to port scan and it can do "os fingerprinting".

Also, if you are on the same network as the Pi, then you should get its MAC address in your arp table.  Raspberry Pi MAC addresses should start with "B8-27-EB".

https://nmap.org/

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28365/what-are-the-possible-ouis-for-the-ethernet-mac-address

https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/06/finding-the-mac-address-of-a-raspberry-pi/

Comment: I'd be happy if I found at least some false positives, but I've found no device at all. nmap did the job, though, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

The following code returns a dict with the IPs of different connections. It works in a Raspberry and on Windows 10, and should probably work on all OS.
I use this for a socket server on a Raspi. From Windows I just use the hostname.

```
info = dict()
conns = psutil.net_if_stats()
ifs = psutil.net_if_addrs()
for conn, snicstats in conns.items():
    if snicstats.isup:
        connifs = ifs[conn]
        for connif in connifs:
            if str(connif.family.name) == 'AF_INET':
                info[conn[:17]] = connif.address
```

Example output on a Raspberry:

> {'lo': '127.0.0.1', 'wlan0': '192.168.0.101'}